# Open text file at end of file

Tags: text-editor, geany

Geany is my main text editor.

I am looking for a way to open a text file where it shows the last few lines of the file AND be able to edit such file.

That would be good for looking at the end of long log files.

Preferably with Geany.

Comment: I am curious as to why you don't just use tail? or are you going to be editing the end of the log files as well?

Comment: Or `ctrl+end` to move to the end of the document in Geany.

Comment: @DK Bose I want to already be at the end when file is opened.

Comment: @ j-money Yes, to also edit said file.

Comment: you might try inspecting the tail, and then using `sed` to edit the file. I'm not sure what edits you're trying to make but I know on my machine I have a cvs file that has ~340,000,000 lines in it and it woudl take up to 10 minutes to open up vim with the cursor at the end, whereas `tail` and `sed` was generally faster! Granted it was only mariginally faster but hey improvements are improvements :)

Answer (score 2):

The `--line` (abbreviated `-l`) command-line option specifies which line number to go to after opening the file.

Presumably, specifying a very high number like 1 billion (1000000000) should ensure it goes to the last line each time.

Answer (score 0):

Since comments are so difficult to edit, I did this.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Ubuntu_Mate 18.04 LTS
#
#  Look at end of text file using Geany.  tail not needed. 
#
# MUCH HELP from thomasrutter at https://askubuntu.com/
#
#
# syslog is in /var/log

cd /home/andy/Downloads
# Send syslog to text file
cat /var/log/syslog > syslog.txt
# using geany, open syslog at the end
geany -l 10000000 syslog.txt
```

"It is always too soon to quit."

Comment: I don't understand what the `cd` and `cat` have to do with the question. And anyway why use `cat` instead of `cp`?

Comment: @wjandrea Is there an advantage in using cp instead of cat? There are several ways of frying chicken.

Comment: Actually, never mind. On [looking it up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30295/117037), it appears it's only a problem for copying binary files. Text files are fine.

Comment: @wjandrea No problem.